# How to reset the user and groups of the contents of a directory to default in Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, xampp

I had to start the xampp server as root every time, otherwise it would say - "this application requires admin privileges". So what I did is, I ran two commands - `sudo chown ankur lampp -R` and `sudo chgrp ankur lampp -R` where "ankur" is my username. Now the `ls -l` showed the following results:

```
total 12940
drwxr-xr-x  5 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 apache2
drwxrwxr-x  2 ankur ankur   12288 Mar  1 20:22 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 build
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 cgi-bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ankur ankur   25750 Mar  1 20:22 ctlscript.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 docs
drwxrwxr-x  3 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 error
drwxr-xr-x  8 ankur ankur    4096 Mar 14 03:36 etc
drwxr-xr-x  9 ankur ankur    4096 Mar 13 17:09 htdocs
drwxr-xr-x  3 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 icons
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 img
drwxr-xr-x 22 ankur ankur   12288 Mar  1 20:25 include
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 info
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ankur ankur      16 Mar  1 20:25 lampp -> /opt/lampp/xampp
drwxr-xr-x 15 ankur ankur   12288 Mar  1 20:29 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 lib64
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 libexec
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 licenses
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar 16 00:47 logs
drwxr-xr-x  7 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 man
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ankur ankur 3361003 Aug 27  2019 manager-linux-x64.run
drwxr-xr-x 14 ankur ankur   12288 Mar  1 20:25 manual
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 modules
drwxr-xr-x  3 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 mysql
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 pear
drwxr-xr-x  3 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 php
drwxr-xr-x 13 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:30 phpmyadmin
drwxr-xr-x  3 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:22 proftpd
-rw-r--r--  1 ankur ankur     904 Mar  1 20:29 properties.ini
-rw-r--r--  1 ankur ankur    3102 Nov 10 15:59 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 ankur ankur   19520 Nov 10 15:59 README-wsrep
-rw-r--r--  1 ankur ankur     647 Feb  9 13:21 RELEASENOTES
drwxr-xr-x  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 48 ankur ankur    4096 Mar  1 20:25 share
drwxrwxrwx  2 ankur ankur    4096 Mar 16 00:52 temp
-rw-r--r--  1 ankur ankur   86263 Nov 10 15:59 THIRDPARTY
-rwx------  1 ankur ankur 9103604 Mar  1 20:30 uninstall
-rw-------  1 ankur ankur  458842 Mar  1 20:30 uninstall.dat
drwxr-xr-x  7 ankur ankur    4096 Mar 16 00:48 var
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ankur ankur   15201 Jul 22  2013 xampp
```

After that I tried running the xampp server, the application still said that it requires admin privileges and **now even on running as root, the mysql is not getting started.**

Can someone please help me in setting the user and groups to default? So that my xampp server can run again as before?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the owner/group of a set of files won't change the fact the application requires to be run as root.  In future avoid changing permissions for installed application files, they ship with the provided values for a reason.

Assuming your XAMPP installation is in `/opt/lampp` you can change the permissions back to root using `chown` like so:

`sudo chown root:root -R /opt/lampp`

Failing that you can always backup your files and re-install the application.

Comment: I did revert them back to root. Still the mysql is not getting started in the xampp now. I guess some user and groups were not daemon, I don't remember properly. How to backup the database? I have a huge one in xampp.